# How to export data into excel from current search in Laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I've problem with my project, I need to export my table from search data in Laravel, how I can do it sir? 
There's my Controller and index.blade.php

Controller.php

```
public function downloadExcel(Request $request, $type)
{
    $data = TABLENAME::get()->toArray();
    return Excel::create('FILENAME', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download($type);
}

public function search(Request $request)
{
$query = Model_items::query();
            if(Input::has('name')) {
                $query->where('name', $getName);
            }
            if(Input::has('phone')) {
                $query->where('phone', $getPhone);
            }
            $dataList = $query->paginate(10);
return view('index', compact('dataList'));
}
```

Index.blade.php

```
                <div class="col-md-4">
                            {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','url'=>'findData','role'=>'search'])  !!}
                            <div style="left: 120%" class="input-group custom-search-form">

                                <input id="cTah" name="cTah" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 10px"/> Name
                                <input type="text" class="iTah" name="name" disabled="" style="float: right;"><br>

                                <input id="cKab" name="cKab" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 10px"/> Phone
                                <input type="text" class="iKab" name="phone" disabled=""  style="float: right;"><br>

                                <br>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="margin-left: 20px">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
                                        </button>
                                     </span>
                                 </span>
                             </div>
                             {!! Form::close() !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed tfix">
                        <thead align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>NAME</b></td>
                            <td><b>PHONE</b></td>
                            <td width="85px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    @foreach($dataList as $key => $view)
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td>{{ $view->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $view->phone }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                    {{ $dataList->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
            <br/>
            <h3>Export File From Database:</h3>
            <div style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 20px;">
                <a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf']) }}"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Export PDF</button></a>
                <a href="{{ url('downloadExcel/xlsx') }}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Export Excel</button></a>
            </div>
            <br/>
```

I use Maat to convert data into Excel, but this is export all data in TABLENAME, how to make this code can export my current data from search?

Answer (score 1):

Simple write your controller code look like

```
if(Input::has('download')) {
    $query = Model_items::query();
    if(Input::has('name')) {
        $query->where('name', $getName);
    }
    if(Input::has('phone')) {
        $query->where('phone', $getPhone);
    }
    $dataList = $query->get();

    return Excel::create('FILENAME', function($excel) use ($dataList) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($dataList)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($dataList);
        });
    })->download($type);

} else {
    $query = Model_items::query();
    if(Input::has('name')) {
        $query->where('name', $getName);
    }
    if(Input::has('phone')) {
        $query->where('phone', $getPhone);
    }
    $dataList = $query->paginate(10);
}

return view('index', compact('dataList'));
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bring up a very old post but any way to do this on Laravel Excel 3.1? Been pulling my hair out trying to figure it out. Is the only way to use FromArray? If so, how?